# How to add alias on post-start hook?

Tags: ddev

I need to add alias for certain commands, but can't figure out how to do this with post-start hooks.

For example, I want `alias ll='ls -lah'`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One could edit ~/.bashrc file in post-start hook.

Like so:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec: sudo echo alias ll=\"ls -lhA\" >> ~/.bashrc
```